# How can I successfully link an assembly program on OS X?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86

I am learning assembly langauage, and reading the book Programming From The Ground Up.
In the first programming example

```
movl $1, %eax #
movl $0, %ebx #
int $0x80      #
```

I can successfully assembly this to object file. But when I run `ld exit.o exit`, the following error shows:

```
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specified, assuming 10.8
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "start", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture x86_64
```

How can I solve this problem? Running environment is MacOS 10.9

Comment: You need to create a global symbol named `start`, at the top of your code. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book you're reading is about assembly programming for Linux systems, not Mac OS X. While they're similar, they're not the same, especially when it comes to low-level programming like this — if you want to follow the directions in this book, set up a Linux virtual machine and use that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Should Ubuntu work for this book? And would you recommend any assembly programming book for macosx?

Comment: Ubuntu will work fine, yes. If you want a book on low-level details of Mac OS X in general, one could hardly ask for better than [Mac OS X Internals: The Book](http://osxbook.com/).

Comment: Note that you have to compile as 32-bit program. In 64-bit Linux programs the system calls do not use "int 0x80" but another instruction. However statically linked 32-bit programs will work fine on 64-bit Linux.

Answer (score 0):

After the object file is built generally a Linker will generate the executable( This command is very specific). Looks like the compiler was built for 32 bit systems and does not recognize x86_64 . I learned 8086 recently with a Dos-Box emulator. Are you mimicking the native environment for it to run smoothly? A 32 bit program may not run on a 64 bit OS with out a little compatibility patching/thinking.

Are you using -macosx 10.8?

Comment: I am using macosx 10.9.4

Answer (score 0):

There is some difference between assembly on osx and assembly on linux.

In linux:

test.s

```
.section .text
.globl _start
_start: 
    movl $1, %eax 
    movl $0, %ebx 
    int $0x80
```

assemble & link & run

```
# as -o test.o test.s
# ld -o test test.o
# ./test 
# echo $?
0
```

In OS X:

test.s

```
.data
 .text
 .globl start
 start:
     nop
     movl $1, %eax
     movl $0, %ebx
     int $0x80
```

assemble & link & run

```
#as -arch i386 -o test.o test.s
#ld -arch i386 -macosx_version_min 10.7 -o test test.o
#./test 
#echo $?
```